# How to remove the unusable space at the bottom of WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, styling

Here it's fine at the top, but when I scroll to the end, it's not good:

[image]

[image]

I can see it's because of this property: HorizontalScrollBarVisibility, but no matter what I set it to, it takes up space. I want it to be gone completely.

If I make the window long enough to show all items, it's gone, so that makes me think it's the vertical scrollbar taking up space and thus making the datagrid show vertical scrollbar space.

```
<Window x:Class="ProfitTracker.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProfitTracker"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    SizeToContent="Width"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    Title="Profit Tracker"
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Height="464">

<Window.Resources>
    <local:NullImageConverter x:Key="nullImageConverter"/>

    <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#1e90ff"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnAlarmStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="#000000"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="RowStyleWithAlternation" TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#141414"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#1e1e1e"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Style.Triggers>

            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value=" "/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitPercentageColor}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Symbol"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitPercentageColor}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Profit"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitPercentageColor}" />
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitColor}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="PNL %"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitPercentageColor}" />
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitColor}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Day %"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeDailyBackColor}" />
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeDailyForeColor}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Hour %"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeHourlyBackColor}" />
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeHourlyForeColor}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Min %"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=PriceChangeMinutelyForeColor}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Net BTC/m"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" Value="{Binding Path=LastMinuteVolumeColor}" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiDataTrigger>

            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="#006400" CornerRadius="0" Padding="0">
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_Track">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="#640000" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Coins}" IsLiveSortingRequested="True" x:Key="MyKey" />

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyKey}}"  GridLinesVisibility="None" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" RowHeaderWidth="0" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowBackground="#282828" RowStyle="{StaticResource RowStyleWithAlternation}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header=" " MinWidth="0" Width="10"/>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Symbol" Width="74">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="4,2,6,2" Source="{Binding IconFile, Converter={StaticResource nullImageConverter}}" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Symbol}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="0" Width="2" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Lowest" Width="64" Binding="{Binding Path=LowestDailyPriceDisplay}" Foreground="#b40000"/>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Price" Width="64">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Path=PriceProgress, Mode=OneWay}" Minimum="0" Maximum="1"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PriceDecimalDisplay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Highest" Width="64" Binding="{Binding Path=HighestDailyPriceDisplay}" Foreground="#00b400"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="0" Width="2" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit Price" Width="64" Binding="{Binding Path=Balance.UnitPriceDisplay}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Width="64" Binding="{Binding Path=Balance.AvailableAmountDisplay}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Capital" Width="64" Binding="{Binding Path=Balance.TotalValueDisplay}" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="0" Width="2" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Profit" Width="64" Binding="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitDisplay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="PNL %" Width="64" Binding="{Binding Path=Balance.ProfitPercentageDisplay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Day %" Width="64" Binding="{Binding Path=PriceChangeInPercentDailyDisplay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Hour %" Width="64" Binding="{Binding Path=PriceChangeInPercentHourlyDisplay}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="0" Width="2" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Min %" Width="64" Binding="{Binding Path=PriceChangeInPercentMinutelyDisplay}"/>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Vol BTC/h" Width="64">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Path=TotalSellVolumePercentage, Mode=OneWay}" Minimum="0" Maximum="1"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LastHourVolumeInBtcDisplay}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Net BTC/m" Width="64" Binding="{Binding Path=LastMinuteVolumeInBtcDisplay}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Border x:Name="DragControl" local:EnableDragHelper.EnableDrag="True" Visibility="Hidden">
        <TextBlock Text=" "/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Your code isn't causing that to appear on my machine, it must be due to a rogue template or something else in your project that isn't included here.

Comment: So you don't see the horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: Nope, not at all. I did have to remove your use of the converter, because you haven't posted the source for that, and the ItemsSource I bound to was a `string[]` (although I doubt that would cause something like this). If you want to post an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I'll be happy to take another look, but it seems like there's something else in your project causing this which you haven't included.

Comment: Actually, hang on...your content seems to extend all the way to the right edge of (and presumably beyond) the list control, in which case its visibility is normal. What exactly are you trying to do, clamp the content so that the scrollbar doesn't appear?

Comment: Yes basically resize the window so it fits the width. I will post updated images that shows the top and the bottom of the window, coz when I am at the top i dont see the horiz scrollbar.

Comment: I will try to make a simple example, but I am also surprised. Because I have a "mini-mode" where I turn off the visibility of some columns and in this mode I didnt see the horiz scrollbar but then I toggled the normal view it was there, then back to mini, it's left there again, so not sure if there is weirder thing going on.

Answer (score 0):

Oh ok, from your comment it sounds like you want the window to auto-size itself to fit the content, correct? WPF windows don't do that by default, but you can enable it with this:

```
<Window
    ...etc....
    SizeToContent="Width">
```